# Умное распознавание на php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, родилась такова задача:
Существует переменная:

```
$Params = "login=Admin;pass:123123";
```

А теперь главное, нужно достать значение *Admin* и занести в переменную **$user**, а значение *123123* тоже достать, но засунуть уже в переменную **$password**.

**Условия:**

1. Использовать массив не можно
2. Admin и 123123 меняются, тобишь для каждого юзера свое, думаю это понятно

Спасибо за внимание :)

Comment: @IamS, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

[Регулярные выражения](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) в помощь.

Comment: @sergiks, та дело в том, что я понятия не имею как такое провернуть, надеялся, что вы хоть подскажите, где можно вычитать как решить такую задачу.

Comment: @IamS: А откуда взялось требование не использовать массивы? Вам ехать или шашечки? То есть распарсить такой формат вручную несложно, но зачем[?](http://files.adme.ru/files/news/part_34/342655/23.jpg)

Comment: а что, если в сторону csv, json?

Comment: Подсказка: [регулярные выражения](http://htmlweb.ru/php/php_regexp.php). Придётся чуть почитать, чтобы [въехать в тему](https://lurkmore.to/RegExp). Примерно как-то так:

    $pattern = "/login=([^;]+);pass:(.+)/";
    if( preg_match( $pattern, $Params, $matches)){
        $user = $matches[1];
        $password = $matches[2];
        printf( 'Login: %s\tpassword: %s\n', $user, $password);
    } else {
        echo "Не попали с паттерном..";
    }

Comment: Согласен с @VladD. Обоснуйте требование "Использовать массив не можно" (с)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без массива – какое-то «мсье знает толк..»

```
$Params = "login=Admin;pass:123123";
list( $user, $password) = explode(';', preg_replace( "/login=([^;]+);pass:(.+)/", "$1;$2", $Params));
```

Но там все равно есть массив, хотя не видно.

А можно просто удалить все лишнее два раза : )

**Upd.**: без массивов, чистый угар.

```
$Params = "login=Admin;pass:123123";
$user = preg_replace( '/^login=([^;]+).+/', '$1', $Params);
$password = preg_replace( '/^[^;]+;pass:(.+)/', '$1', $Params);
```

**Upd.2**: без регулярных выражений. Сломается, если в пароле или логине будет строка "`;pass=`", что маловероятно, но возможно.

```
$Params = "login=Admin;pass:123123";
parse_str( str_replace( ';pass:', '&password=', $Params));
$user = $login;

printf( "Логин: %s    пароль: %s\n", $user, $password);
```

Comment: Не-не, чистый угар - это посимвольно по строке идти :)

Comment: @sergiks, да, работает спасибо) А вот только password оно не находит, login=qweqwe;password=123 так и записывает, но логин обнаруживает и запоминает правильно

Answer (score 2):

> Использовать массив не можно

Наблюдаю избыточную концентрацию свободного времени.

http://ideone.com/DbwXXg

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый, а Вы случаем зубы не через ухо чистите?

а)explode 3 раза. 1 раз разделитель ; . 2 раз разделитель = . 3 : .
б) preg_match

В обеих случаях массив используется. Самому интересно как без массивов сделать.

**UPD**: Вот решение без массивов:

```
$Params = "login=Admin;pass:123123";
$string = strpos($Params, ";");

$one = substr($Params, 0, $string);
$oneString = strpos($one,'=');
$login = substr($one, $oneString + 1);

$two = substr($Params,$string + 1);
$twoString = strpos($two,':');
$password = substr($two, $twoString + 1);
echo 'login = '.$login.' password = '.$password;
```

Результат выполнения:

```
login = Admin password = 123123
```

.